Advance lever stuck on Praktica BMS electronic
I started having an issue yesterday with my camera. I loaded a new roll of film in correctly and advanced the lever to feed it properly onto the spool. No issues there but I noticed that the advance lever stopped working and the shutter button doesn't fire. It's like everything has seized up.
The dial with numbers so to speak has wound up all the way so that I'm unable to align the number 1 to start counting the pictures captured etc. Luckily I didn't take any images so could open the back and roll in the film again. I then tried to manually wind the spool to see if this triggers anything but it won't budge.
Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Remove the film that's in the camera and start again. Read and follow all instructions exactly as in the camera manual. Ensure your batteries are good. Try to get the camera shutter to fire without any film loaded - could be interesting to do this with the back open, to visually inspect at the same time.
